# Can I Replace the motor on a 450w impact drill with a 400w motor from my other drill.?

Tags: repair, drill

I realize off the bat this runs the risk of doubling my problems but here goes. 
I currently have a z1j-hda-13t 450w impact drill which motor seems to be seized.

I was wondering aside from being less powerful, would it be feasible to replace the 450w with the 400w motor from another drill?
Or would the drive chain having been setup for a 450w create to much torque on the 400w and just burn it out?

*I know someone will say why not just use the 400w drill and I have been. But the overall size of the drills is marginally different such that some of the attachments won't fit in the 400w's head and the head from the 450w won't fit in the housing of the 400w.* Hence the above question.

Just as a p.s. Both drills have a a hammer and screw option.

Comment: That's a $5-$15 drill at bulk-prices (500 off) on Alibaba. If the motor fits the moulded housings and couples to the gearbox, it should work as well as you can expect from a $10 drill.

Comment: Agree with answer below that you won't be able to cannibalize. But why not have fun taking apart (and possibly fixing) the broken drill?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we expect you to meet us halfway with a fair bit of effort on solving the problem yourself.  It's clear you haven't even so much as taken the drills apart to see if the motors will fit.

Comment: I watch a YouTube channel where a guy takes apart power tools to see how well they are made.  The insides of each drill are very specialized and custom built for each application. It's not like they all use the same basic motors.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - If you go to a place like a Harbor Freight store it is interesting to notice that a lot of their power tools use the same motor housing and hand grip assembly for a range of different types of tool functions.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, that's true, but the motor shaft have gears pressed onto them, and I wonder how similar that initial sun gear is?  Also, OP didn't even mention they were the same brand.  For a low cost tool, I'd probably take it apart just to see if it would work, because why not?

Comment: @jphi1618 - Thank you. unfortunately i'm not sure on the brands as they were both "no names", don't even have the model for the 400w(sticker came off). I will take a closer look at the sun gear and see how it is connected when i fully disassemble the 450w as will be seeing if I can figure out whats wrong with it. I like to tinker with broken things, typically without much success so far but hey it is already broken. I learn as I go so sometimes i have questions others may consider stupid and plainly obvious. As i say below will go all out when i get a replacement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the motors have identical sizes, identical mounting means, identical output shafting and identical wiring connections then there is no chance of this even being feasible. You already mention that various aspects of the two drills including the cases and attachment options are slightly different sizes so it is highly likely that there are internal differences as well. Take note of how much the case of modern drills (and other tools as well) is integral to holding all internal components including the motor, gear train, brushes if applicable, wiring and switches and it becomes clear that the motors are likely to be different as well.

It also seems foolish to cannibalize a working tool to repair a broken tool. It is far better to realize that tools have a lifetime, especially if they are used a lot in a trade or have been subjected to a lot of hours of use, and that they will require replacement from time to time. Higher end tools can sometimes be cost effectively be repaired by purchasing replacement parts but it is often the case that it is almost better to just replace broken tools with new ones.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. you have given me a number of things to consider. I do realise in this day and age most appliances are made with a life cycle in mind else our economies wouldn't survive. I unfortunately don't have the $ to replace the 450w, so thought with some minor modding i may be able to get it to work out for a time. You are right though, cannibalizing a working drill in hope could just be a complete waste. Still something i'd like to play around with once i have a replacement though. For my own interest. Thanks again